# How to import Java EE classes to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I already have installed Java SDK following which, I later also Downloaded Java EE which was not automatically Installed in Eclipse. How do I import the Java EE libraries in Eclipse?

Comment: Here is the way I have mentioned:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840315/how-do-i-get-java-ee-to-work/25840471#25840471

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download and install/unpack your favorite Java EE container (for web applications use Tomcat)

Download and start the Java EE edition of Eclipse

In the Server panel create a new local server corresponding to the above Java EE container.

Create a new "Web -> Dynamic Web Project" using the server defined above.  Set the "Servlet API level" to 2.4 or 2.5 depending on your needs.

The new project will have access to the appropriate Java EE libraries.

Comment: You're welcome.  Took me a while to figure out - it is a bit backward.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to use the **[p2 mechanism](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Update_UI_Users_Guide)** (to rpovisioning system to update eclipse, if you are using eclipse**3.5** Galileo) to get **[WTP (Web Tool Platform) SDK](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ)**.

The SDK comes with **[JST (j2ee Standard Tools Project)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/main.php)**, extend eclipse platform with support for building multi-tier J2EE applications.

[image]

---

Another (extreme) solution would be to get the [J2EE edition of eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages) which includes all you need (you can then refer to your previous workspace -- through [an eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) -- in order to retrieve exactly your projects you were working one)

Comment: +1 for J2EE edition of Eclipse, it's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) along with the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin. This will import all of the packages you need for you.

Comment: If at all possible, go this way!