# Creating a Generic Java EE Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

My question is something similar to this one:
[How to import Java EE classes to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448167/how-to-import-java-ee-classes-to-eclipse)

But I'm just creating a sample Message Producer and not a web project. My initial problem was how to import the needed classes.

I've already had 2 different approaches to this:
1) Add the individual libraries (e.g. jms.jar)
2) Created a server for Glassfish as suggested in the question above and created a new Java EE Utility Project in eclipse.

Both approaches work fine but I want something more generic: Creating a project which has access to Java EE libraries and without installing and specifying a server. How can this be done? (i.e. What to install, what options need to be set in eclipse etc)

I already have the following:
- Eclipse Helios IDE for Java EE Developers
- JDK 1.6
- Java EE 6U1 SDK (which already has Glassfish)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [glassfish tools bundle for Eclipse](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/) would work for you.