# How do I get Java EE to work?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have the Java EE version of Eclipse.  But whenever I try to import any packages contained in Java EE, the program says "import javax.mail cannot be resolved"  None of the packages contained in Java EE work.

Am I missing something?  I assumed EE was the same as SE, but every time I try to download EE they seem to want me to make a glassfish server.  Do I really need to do that just to get EE to work?  I do not care about getting glassfish to work at all.  At this point I hope to never use glassfish.

Comment: EE is Enterprise Edition, and if you don't use glassfish you must choose some other EE compatible container. It sounds like you don't really know what you want, but you might consider looking at [Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools/sts).

Comment: Which server you use in your JavaEE program?I think you add JavaMail.jar in your classpath (e.g. under WEB-INF/lib) and it may be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add server runtime libraries.The server runtime libraries have all the JavaEE libraries.
To make it work,install a Java EE server like Glassfish or Tomcat or JBoss etc.
Right click on your project in eclipse->Configure BuildPath->Click on Libraries->Click on Add Library->Click on Server Runtime->Select the server which you have installed.

Comment: To elaborate, the Eclipse IDE for Java EE makes it easier to write Java EE applications, but you still need the classes--from a Java EE runtime or otherwise--to compile against.

Comment: Yes,I have described the way as to how it can be done.

Comment: Hmm, first time something seems to make sense.  I installed Java EE but I need to figure out how to install this server then.  Because the list of servers is empty when I do that.

Comment: Mostly servers come in Zip,just unzip it and put at proper location.No seperate installation required.Then in eclipse provide the path to unzipped server folder and server will be added

Comment: Finding the proper location is next to impossible.  They really bury any sort of option.  However i managed to do it, and got glassfish up and running.

And it doesn't work.  At all.  Apparently the Eclipse IDE for Java EE cannot use Java EE under any circumstances.

If you can go here http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and get that Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (64bit) install and actually use stuff from Java EE in it (i.e. import javax.mail.*) then you have done the impossible.

So I installed NetBeans for Java EE.  Works perfectly from the start.

Comment: probably you need to add javamail.jar in classpath

Comment: I am able to run on the eclipse ide for Java EE Developers.Please add the javamail.jar to the lib folder.